# Can you run OLS with duplicates for control variables but different outcome and dependent variables?

Tags: regression, least-squares, spss, experiment-design

So my situation is as follows: I have done a survey experiment asking respondents to hypothetically allocate 100 euros between 4 asset classes, of which one is crypto assets. I then repeat this another 3 times, except here the other assets are assigned an ESG value of 70, whereas crypto assets get assigned 50, 70, and 90 for each of those scenarios respectively. Therefore a single respondent has 4 different allocations.

I want to examine whether the effect of introducing ESG ratings to crypto assets is significant to crypto asset portfolio allocation. I cannot use RM ANOVA because there are two treatments here effectively; ESG ratings for crypto assets and ESG rating for the other assets, of which one changes 4 times (no ESG to crypto, low, mid and high) whereas one is just binary (no ESG to other assets, ESG rating to other assets) with the condition, as can be observed, is that if ESG ratings are not assigned to other assets, they will also not be assigned to crypto assets (see experiment)  so two factor ANOVA is also not possible.

A possible solution I had discussed with my supervisor was that since each respondent has 4 observations of what should be a single dependent variable (crypto allocation), we could create that variable but duplicate every response in the data set so that there are a total of 4 rows per respondent. Where the control variables are the same values for each respondent, but now have different values for crypto allocation, dependable on the treatment variables ESG_crypto_1, ESG_crypto_2, ESG_crypto_3 (dummy variables for each respective scenario, baseline is no ESG whatsoever) and ESG_other (dummy variable whether ESG ratings are assigned to other assets or not).

of course, the right data for these variables would be matched so that for example in the row where ESG_crypto_2, has value 1, the other dummies are zero, ESG_other has value 1 and the complimentary allocation towards crypto assets for that scenario is the value for Crypto_allocation. I could then run OLS.

Is this possible to do and if not, why not and what is the alternative? (Using SPSS btw)

Side information: There is the issue of heteroskedasticity, which I resolve by using robust standard errors.

Please let me know if this is a suitable solution! :)